# How to scale div from jquery css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the javascript function to flip the div, but when i call this function the div should scale from `0.01 to 1` ratio. how can i do this?

css:

```
 transform: scaleX(0.01);
 transform: scaleX(1);
```

Javascript:

```
function flip1(){
    $('#category-1').delay(100).css('display', 'none');
    $('.box-1').delay(100).css('display', 'block');
    $('.box-1').transition({
        perspective: '100px',
        rotateY: '360deg'
      },200)  
    setTimeout(startSlidecat1, 2000);
  }
```

right now it is rotating slowly,  instead of rotate i want to add 
`scaleX` from 0.01 to 1 with same delay i have right now.

Comment: Don't use JS to rotate it - it's slow performance, specially on mobile devices. Instead define a CSS class that does the rotation and add the class using JS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be done be with simple css

```
//scale(0.2,0.2) you can change the values according to your requirement
```

> CSS to flip and scale

```
.cards{
    margin:30px;
    perspective: 500;
    -webkit-perspective: 500;
    -moz-perspective: 500;
    -ms-perspective: 500;
    -o-perspective: 500;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#5000FF;
    transform-style:preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    position:absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
    /* Animate the transitions */
    -webkit-transition:0.8s; text-align:center;
    -moz-transition:0.8s; text-align:center;
    -ms-transition:0.8s; text-align:center;
    -o-transition:0.8s; text-align:center;
    transition:0.8s; text-align:center;

}

.flip{
  transform:rotateY(180deg) scale(0.2,0.2);
  -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg) scale(0.2,0.2);
  -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
  background-color:#FF5959;

}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/AaU6v/134/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mh9E6eZXDrnuCwTGNPOD?p=preview)

Css:

```
div{
  height: 200px;
  width:200px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transition:all 2s linear;
  -moz-transition:all 2s linear;
  -ms-transition:all 2s linear;
  -o-transition:all 2s linear;
  transition:all 2s linear;
}
.rotate{
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg) scale(2.0);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg) scale(2.0);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(360deg) scale(2.0);
  -o-transform: rotateY(360deg) scale(2.0);
  transform: rotateY(360deg) scale(2.0);
}
```